# Program crashes whenever it gets string data from an another activity

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin-coroutines

I was just making a simple program that sends string that's typed in an EditText into a TextView in another activity, I'm a beginner and was following a kotlin tutorial on the internet, the program would crash whenever it gets the string from the 1st activity, The code of the 1st activity looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {

        val message: String? = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.sameer).text.toString()
        val kash = Intent(this, kos::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("sameer", message)
        startActivity(kash)



    }
}
}
```

and the code for the 2nd activity goes like this:

```
class kos: AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.kos)
    val kanye: Bundle? = intent.extras
    val shaheer = kanye!!.getString("sameer")
    Toast.makeText(this, shaheer , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.UserisHambola).text = shaheer

}




}
```

I've tried to check when does the error start to happen, it appears that it starts to happen after declaring variable "shaheer" in the 2nd activity, if I delete that code with all the other codes after it, the program doesn't crash, I don't know why does this crash happen, Thank you for your time <3

Comment: Running the app a couple of times probably will generate a java error stacktrace, which you could paste here (it helps a lot)

Comment: https://scontent.fcai20-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/285631893_591461502184127_4667645372426863987_n.png?_nc_cat=104&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=xu4Oomw8F1oAX_4jxIj&_nc_ht=scontent.fcai20-2.fna&oh=03_AVKrjNDupP5hiyJhQIGrhGfj6YncON7Ak35E6g8hcN_-qA&oe=62C08D48


that's the log bro

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `kanye!!.getString("sameer")` with `kanye?.getStringExtra("sameer") ?: "no data"`. This way the program will not crash if no value is passed under "sameer" `key` and the default `"no data"` will be stored to `val shaheer`. If you see `no data` in the toast, you passed the variable between activities incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in `MainActivity`:

```
    val kash = Intent(this, kos::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("sameer", message)
    startActivity(kash)
```

You put the extra with the key "sameer" into the `Intent` referenced by the variable `intent`. You probably want to put the extra into the `Intent` referenced by the variable `kash`. Try this instead:

```
    val kash = Intent(this, kos::class.java)
    kash.putExtra("sameer", message)
    startActivity(kash)
```